# HTML Map Areas Coordinates

Tags: html

How do I take the exact coordinates of an image using and reproducing the border?

```
<map name="corpo-donna" id="body">
    <area shape="rect" coords="205,56,269,142" href="#" id="viso_donna" alt="viso-donna" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="200,140,160,170" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="163,217,173,231,200,174,178,151,153,214,96,271,105,287,173,231,163,214,163,208" href="#" id="braccio_donna_sx" alt="braccio-donna-sx" />
</map>
```

Comment: Could you give more information (you want the picture border, or like the arm as in your example)? Would a simple program like GIMP or Photoshop be enough for you to get the coordinates you want (they display this info usually on the bottom tab)?

Comment: you excuse me, then I have an image of the human body, and I would take the coordinates of each individual part, such as the arm, head, etc. ... and I implemented a plugin that hover above the one hand, it shows .. but when it happens it is bad because you will not see the sharp edges of the selected part ... like this [http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html] coordinates have the precise shape of the states

Answer (score 0):

On this example you sent they make use of CANVAS element and I guess this should be the way to go.

It gives you more freedom as the map tag to make drawings.

You only have to "lay it over" the image you want to draw and make it appear the desired img when you rover the desired part.

- For a gentle introduction to canvas check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)
- And to learn how to access the mouse position and such I recommend [this "paint" app](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/)

Hope it works the way you want.

P.s.: you need some javascript functions to get the functionality working.